# Rename wordress plugin

Tags: plugins

i installed a 3rd party saloon booking plugin on my wordpress site.
But i need to rename this plugin name as mysaloon plugin.
And im expecting that name will appear even on source code.
Is it possible to change a plugin name like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the name of the plugin but keep in mind future updates will not work.

Here is the plugin directory structure

yoursite\wp-content\plugins\ [editing-plugin-folder]

open the folder you will find a .php file in there, edit the file using any editor. you can change the name of the plugin in commented area

```
/*
Plugin Name: Name according to you
Plugin URI:

*/
```

save the file refresh your wp-admin dashboard and there you go .